# How to fix [!] No podspec found for `get_thumbnail_video` in `.symlinks/plugins/get_thumbnail_video/ios`

Tags: ios, flutter, pubspec

I have this error on IOS for this flutter package 'get_thumbnail_video' that is normaly compatible IOS.

I tried a lot of things but not working. Is there a problem on the package ?

Comment: To help you solve the issue you should add code, things you tried and more information in general. If you only wanted to tell that the package is not working, is stack overflow not the place to do it.